# randomly remove element from array java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am removing elements from an array in the below code. In this particular code I am removing the element at pos 2. How would I go about removing a random element in this array?

```
public class QuestionOneA2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 5;
    int pos = 2;

    String[] countries = {"Brazil", "France", "Germany", "Canada", "Italy", "England"};

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if(i == pos) {
                countries[i] = countries[size];
            }
            System.out.println(countries[i]);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: use e.g. `int size = countries.length - 1` or just `countries.length - 1` instead of a fixed size; otherwise you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this element:

```
int randomLocation = new Random().nextInt(countries.length);
// countries[randomLocation]  <--- this is the "random" element.
```

Or in 1 line:

```
countries[(new Random()).nextInt(countries.length)];
```

So in order to actually remove the element you can use [`ArrayUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html):
First import these

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;
```

And then:

```
countries = ArrayUtils.removeElement(countries, countries[(new Random()).nextInt(countries.length)]);
```

If you **really** don't want to use `ArrayUtils` then you can use:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(countries));
list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(countries[(new Random()).nextInt(countries.length)]));
countries = list.toArray(countries);
```

Comment: What do I put inside my for loop if I do this?

Comment: @StudentCoder I edited my answer with a clearer command to use (delete your `for` loop)

Comment: Thanks, I am actually trying to solve this question using a for loop though

Comment: There is no use for a `for` loop in this program it's a waste of space and time.

Comment: This is the first part of a 2 part question I am trying to do which will then ask the user to input the missing country and I was instructed to use a for loop, am I looking at his completely the wrong way?

Comment: You can hold the the missing item by `missingItem = countries[(new Random()).nextInt(countries.length)];` and then just ask the user which item bla bla... And if he guesses right (i.e. guesses `missingItem`) then he is correct..

Comment: @StudentCoder did it work for you eventually? If my answer helped, please consider accepting it by clicking the green check mark next to it. It helps people in the future who might have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Random r = new Random();
int result = r.nextInt(size);
//and select/remove countries[result]
```

This give you a pseudo-random number between 0 and 5 (exclusive).
Be careful with your `size` variable, I think it's not well defined.

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not mind the order of the elements, you can also achieve this behaviour in constant time:

```java
public <E> E removeRandom(List<E> list, Random random) {
    if (list.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    int index = random.nextInt(list.size());
    int lastIndex = list.size() - 1;

    E element = list.get(index);
    list.set(index, list.get(lastIndex));
    list.remove(lastIndex);

    return element;
}
```